# 2D Convolution notation confusion?

Tags: convolution

We can express 2D convolution between $f(m,n)$ and $h(m,n)$ as following

\begin{align}
g(m,n) &= \displaystyle \sum_{k_1=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{k_2=-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\!_{k_1,k_2}}h(m-k_1,n-k_2)\tag{1}\\
 &=f(m,n)*h(m,n)\tag{2}
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
h(m,n) = \begin{cases}
h_{m,n} & {0\leq m \leq L_r, 0\leq n \leq L_c}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
f(m,n) = f_{m,n} \forall {-\infty\leq m \leq \infty, -\infty\leq n \leq \infty}
\end{equation}

From (1), it seems as if the value of g at location (m,n) is equal to the double sum. But (2) is more like the input-output relationship that can be represent as. here $f(m,n)$ and $g(m,n)$ represent the entire 2D signals.
Can someone please figure out where I am making a mistake
[image]

Comment: Are the functions $f$, $g$ and $h$ with integer domains?

Comment: And I don't understand why you think there is a mistake between lines (1) and (2).

Comment: (1) n (2) are correct but I am confused about what they mean. From (2), I conclude that the 2D convolution of entire 2D data f(m,n) with filter h(m,n) gives the complete 2D matrix g(m,n), whereas from (1) it seems that the value of function g at single location (m,n) can be computed using the double sum. so (1) is taking about a single point and (2) is about the whole data. Thats where I am missing the point

Comment: I looked for 1D case. at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution short hand notation is written as $(f*h)[n]$ but at http://cnx.org/contents/febae08d-0391-4973-a2e1-fcac232bcb1c@4/Convolution---Discrete-time it is written as $y(n)=f(n)*h(n)$ . what is the difference between these two notations.

Comment: It is like saying differentiation $\frac d{dx}$ is an operation on a function but not a particular value of the function:
$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\ f(x)\tag3$$
and the three $x$'s do not even have the same meaning, unlike
$$f'(x_0) = \left.\frac d{dx} \ f(x)\right|_{x = x_0}\tag4$$
But it is possible to write the formula of $f'$ at a single location $x$, without using $\frac d{dx}$:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\tag5$$
And indeed, $(5)$ is a definition of the $\frac d{dx}$ operation in $(3)$, like $(1)$ is a definition of the (2D discrete-time) $*$ operation in $(2)$.

Comment: thanks … you made an effort here.